# Side by Side Divs with a Media Query giving the wrong order

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Am sure this is very obvious... but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have two divs that I need above one another when the media width is small, and beside each other when large. The right one is fixed width, and the left is variable.  However, when the media width is small, they end up in the wrong order. If I swap around the divs in the html, they no longer line up nicely.

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/CwMTU/2/

HTML

```
<div class="right"> right content fixed width </div>

<div class="left"> left navbar variable width </div>
```

CSS

```
.right {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;}

.left{
    margin-right: 200px;}


@media (max-width: 500px) {       
.left {
    width: 100%;}

.right { 
    width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Well worst case scenario you can always create a copy of the nav bar div as the first element in your html order. Then hide/show based on media query. After creating a responsive website, I find it a lot of times I had to do this due to design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did it using an extra wrapper div and `display:table/table-cell` (set back to block in the media query)

http://jsfiddle.net/CwMTU/4/

Comment: as long as you can add the extra wrapper, this is the safer way to go

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the `<div>`'s

```
<div class="left">
   left navbar variable width
</div>

<div class="right">
    right content fixed width
</div>
```

And change the `float` in both classes.. Add a `width:100%;` with a `margin-right` of `-200px`, to get your right div next to it.

```
.right {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background:green;
}

.left{
    background:red;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:-200px;

}
```

JsFiddle is updated with this:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {

.left {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right:0;             <--------
}
```

Your **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CwMTU/6/)** but updated

Comment: what if the content of the nav bar is long enough for 2 lines or long enough to go behind the right div? like this http://jsfiddle.net/CwMTU/5/

Comment: i dont understand the question... and if i understand is it a question that is irrelevant for this mather...

Comment: Look at the fiddle I posted, the text of the left side div goes behind the div on the right

Comment: You mean that he needs to add `margin-right:0;` in the `.left` of the `@media`

Comment: My fiddle in the comment shows at width > 500 (green on left, red on right) the text content of the red div goes behind the green div. Meaning part of the text is covered/cut off. I am not looking at the mobile view (less than 500)

Comment: i See i seee, thanx trying to fix it